# Get Integration Data Rules Status

Tags: apex, integration, geolocation

Is it possible to get information about current status of integration in apex? In this case it is Geocodes service
[image]

I would like to give community user feedback if their address that their just provided is "correct" meaning if *MailingLatitude* and *MailingLongitude* fields has been populated.

Comment: Best you can do out of the box is look at Data Integration Status available on each record: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.integration_rule_info_fields.htm&type=5 and https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ddc_data_integration_create_update_info_report.htm&type=5 . If you're a developer, you can hit a 3rd party geocoding and address validation service and get this info based on their physical address and/or IP. Lots of these services out there, some are free and most are low-cost.

Comment: But it is not possible to query that object, right?

Comment: @LightShrimp What object? The  Data Integration Status is retrievable, see linked docs.